# Stacking a relative layout and a linear

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello I'm trying to put an AutoScrollViewPager and underneath a linear layout in horizotal to stack two buttons just so as not to have a success ... The scroll is hiding the linear layout. a help?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.htcursos.tucapp.LoginActivity"
    android:background="#ff000000">

   <cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager.AutoScrollViewPager
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/viewPager">

   </cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager.AutoScrollViewPager>

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/doots"
       android:layout_below="@+id/viewPager"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:gravity="center">


   <Button
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Login"
       android:textSize="16sp"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
       android:id="@+id/login"
       android:textColor="#fff"
       android:background="@null"/>

   <Button
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Cadastrar"
       android:textSize="16sp"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
       android:id="@+id/cadastrar"
       android:textColor="#fff"
       android:background="@null"/>

   </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Preview:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbUoc.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
<cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager.AutoScrollViewPager
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/viewPager">
```

I think your mistake is that your height from your AutoScrollViewPager is set to match_parent, set it to wrap_content

**EDIT**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager.AutoScrollViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager.AutoScrollViewPager>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <Button 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 1"/>
        <Button 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So you're trying to get the linearlayout below the autoscroll?

Comment: Exactly, I want to put two buttons inside the linear, one on top of the other, Login and Register

Comment: It worked very well! But you can see that not my example, I put a linear layout, with id "doots", I would like it to be in the middle, between the View and the buttons.